# How to continue loop when a data frame contains NULL rows (but is.null=FALSE)?

Tags: r

I would like to continue loop when the loop encounters a data frame (x) with NULL rows, i.e.

> nrow(x)
>   NULL

I have tried the following code that doesn't work

```
if (nrow(x)<1) next

Error in if (nrow(x) < 1) next : argument is of length zero
```

Comment: Could `is.null(x)` be an option?

Comment: is.null(x) FALSE - meaning that the data frame is not empty I suppose?

Comment: Are you sure `x` is a data frame? The command `nrow(x)` returns `0` for me. What is the output of `str(x)`?

Comment: If `nrow(x)` is `NULL`, then it isn't a data frame. See if `length` or `NROW` (which does the right thing when given a data frame or a vector) works for you.

Comment: @Sven Hohenstein: No you are right, x is not a data frame. The answer you gave below as your alternative worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
if(is.null(x) || length(dim(x)) < 2 || !nrow(x)) next
```

or, alternatively,

```
if(!is.data.frame(x) || !nrow(x)) next
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
if(is.null(x) || nrow(x) ==0) next
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if (is.null(nrow(x))==TRUE) next
```

Is this enough?