# Including NULL entries in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, null

I'm pulling values into a new dataframe. The values come from an object with columns that contain lists and I need to pull specific values from specific columns/lists for each row. I've created a for loop that iterates through each row, pulls out the various values, and inputs them into the dataframe, however some of the entries in the lists are NULL. The for loop inputs these then errors out (Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero) without iterating through the rest of the dataframe. I need to include the NULL entries in the dataframe so those entries cannot just be skipped.

The object that I'm pulling from is approximately 7 columns, four of which contain nested values in lists. The dataframe I'm putting things into (df) is just an empty dataframe that matches the dimensions for the values I'm pulling (e.g., 13 columns).

The for loop looks like this, except with 13+ values to pull:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(object)){
   df[i, 1] <- object[[3]][[i]]
   df[i, 2] <- object[[6]][[i]]$mean_r
   df[i, 3] <- object[[6]][[i]]$true_score_sd_rho
   df[i, 4] <- object[[9]][[i]]$true_score$CI_LL_95
   df[i, 5] <- object[[9]][[i]]$true_score_Q[[3]]
}
```

I've tried to include !is.na() in the loop in some form but apart from doing this for all 13+ entries it doesn't seem to work. Additionally I've tried fixes from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469452/how-to-continue-loop-when-a-data-frame-contains-null-rows-but-is-null-false), which makes the full loop run, but doesn't input any values into the dataframe. I'm hoping for something that inputs NA values when it hits a NULL entry, then carries right on with the next row.

I'm not married to this version of the code either, if there is a sleeker/faster/better way to do this I'd be happy to learn about it!

Comment: the code is incorrect. you cannot put all those values in a single cell. ie either `df[i, ]` `df[i,2]`, `df[i,3]` etc

Comment: @Onyambu's correct comment notwithstanding - you would be overwriting the same entry lots of times in the loop - without a reproducible example (i.e., knowing the structure of `object` and `df`), it will be impossible for us to help troubleshoot the root cause of the error.  Once we solve the error, there will be a way to solve the other problem as well.

Comment: Sorry, error corrected now, should be inputting into different columns as @Onyambu pointed out. I've added as much detail as I can on the structure of object and df.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Post:
There are other ways I could solve this, but this way is straightforward,I expect it would work for you.

```
# problem 
df <- data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3)
df[1,1] <- 9
df[1,2] <- NULL
df[1,3] <- 9
df


# solution by hand
df <- data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3)
df[1,1] <- 9
df[1,2] <- if(is.null(NULL)){NA} else{9}
df[1,3] <- 9
df

# solution by your own function
null_to_na <- function(x){if(is.null(x)){NA} else {x} }
df <- data.frame(a=1,b=2,c=3)
df[1,1] <- 9
df[1,2] <- null_to_na(NULL)
df[1,3] <- 9
df
```

---

Original Post : Please make a reproducible example, because I cant see from what you wrote and your code, what your problem stems from. it does not seem to be a problem of getting an NA and inserting it into a data.frame because that is not controversial/hard.

```
df <- data.frame()
df[1,1] <- 1
df[1,2] <- NA
df[1,3] <- 3
df
```

result ->

```
  V1 V2 V3
1  1 NA  3
```

if instead of passing NA, I pass numeric(0) then I would get an error

```
df[1,2] <- numeric(0)
# Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero
```

so perhaps that rather than getting NA values you are getting 0 length data ?

Comment: Having trouble creating a reproducible example with the object I'm trying to pull from as I'm not that experienced. It's an object with 22 rows, 9 columns, 4 of which contain lists with nested numbers. In certain rows, the value I'm trying to pull is from a list that is NULL which is where the error seems to be coming from.

Comment: I made a best guess on your issue, and how you could solve it; edited my post